# Help identifying the font for BonLook's logo

Tags: font-identification

It would be helpful if anyone can identify this font, or something similar.

I've tried the What The Font search engine, however it gave me not so good results.

[image: BonLook Logo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for something similar, this kind of font is commonly referred to as a "[Slab Serif](http://www.myfonts.com/tags/slab+serif/)" font.

It is not an exact match, but the closest I could find was [Arvo](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Arvo). The designer may have possibly used it as the base and tweaked it slightly (most noticeably the K)

[image: BonLook Logo]